# Use default interface method as controller action ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

How to use default interface methods as MVC controller actions? Since interface methods exists on interface type, they aren't discovered by ASP as actions by default. Example:

```
public interface IGetEntityControllerMixin<TEntity> : IControllerBase
    where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
{
    IRepository<TEntity> Repository { get; }

    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<TEntity>> Get(int id)
    {
        var entity = await Repository.GetByIdAsync(id);

        return entity == null ? NotFound() : Ok(entity);
    }
}
public interface IPagingEntityControllerMixin<TEntity> : IControllerBase
    where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
{ ... }

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyEntityController : ControllerBase,
                                  IGetEntityControllerMixin<MyEntity>,
                                  IPagingEntityControllerMixin<MyEntity>
{
    public IRepository<MyEntity> Repository { get; }
    public MyEntityController(IRepository<MyEntity> repository)
        => Repository = repository;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea if it will work, but you might want to look at `IActionDescriptorProvider`.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar its readonly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.actiondescriptorcollection.items?view=aspnetcore-6.0 and default implementatoin is internal https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/dea887d2b8a80256c3e2467cf773b87dc26c864b/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.cs

Comment: That's not the same thing at all.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Ok, sorry I was looking at `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider`. [ControllerActionDescriptorProvider](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/dea887d2b8a80256c3e2467cf773b87dc26c864b/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ApplicationModels/ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.cs) which is `IActionDescriptorProvider` is also `internal sealed`

Comment: `IActionDescriptorProvider` is an interface. You can implement your own concrete class.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar yeah, but if I provide my own implementation I must implement what it does by default + my behavior. I can't inherit default implementation and it's using some internal classes as well and I don't want to reimplement half of MVC.

Comment: Um, as far as I'm aware, you can register multiple. Anyway, I was just suggesting that you have a look at it as it might be the correct avenue for adding extra abnormal controller actions.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar actually I need to implement `IApplicationModelProvider` to add additional actions to controller. `IActionDescriptorProvider` doesn't have enough context. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register `IApplicationModelProvider` to inform MVC about those actions. But to play well with other parts of MVC, we also need to annotate method with metadata. Unfortunately metadata extraction routines are packed inside `DefaultApplicationModelProvider` and marked as `internal`. Here we are reusing `DefaultApplicationModelProvider` to populate metadata via reflection.

```cs
internal sealed class ControllerDefaultInterfaceMethodActionModelProvider : IApplicationModelProvider
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly Type _type;
    private IApplicationModelProvider? _defaultModelProvider;

    private IApplicationModelProvider DefaultModelProvider => _defaultModelProvider
                                                                  ??= _serviceProvider.GetServices<IApplicationModelProvider>()
                                                                                      .First(x => x.GetType() == _type);

    public ControllerDefaultInterfaceMethodActionModelProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        // Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.DefaultApplicationModelProvider;
        _type = Type.GetType("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.DefaultApplicationModelProvider, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core")!;
        Debug.Assert(_type != null);
    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuted(ApplicationModelProviderContext context) { }

    public void OnProvidersExecuting(ApplicationModelProviderContext context)
    {
        const BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;

        // internal ActionModel? CreateActionModel(TypeInfo typeInfo, MethodInfo methodInfo)
        var createActionModelParams = new object [2];
        var createActionModel = _type.GetMethod("CreateActionModel", bindingFlags)!;
        // internal ParameterModel CreateParameterModel(ParameterInfo parameterInfo)
        var createParameterModelParams = new object [1];
        var createParameterModel = _type.GetMethod("CreateParameterModel", bindingFlags)!;

        foreach (ControllerModel controllerModel in context.Result.Controllers)
        {
            var controllerType = controllerModel.ControllerType;
            createActionModelParams[0] = controllerType;

            foreach (Type @interface in controllerType.ImplementedInterfaces)
            {
                var mapping = controllerType.GetInterfaceMap(@interface);
                for (var i = 0; i < mapping.InterfaceMethods.Length; ++i)
                {
                    MethodInfo interfaceMethod = mapping.InterfaceMethods[i];
                    MethodInfo targetMethod = mapping.TargetMethods[i];

                    // check is method implemented by interface itself
                    if (targetMethod != interfaceMethod)
                        continue;

                    // based on https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d3b7623a90d79719c0efe5fa0098f698176efa16/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ApplicationModels/DefaultApplicationModelProvider.cs#L65-L96
                    // You can also register interface properties via CreatePropertyModel, but I don't think it's a good idea
                    // Also you can augment `controllerModel` based on some attributes on `@interface` type (mainly controllerModel.Filters)

                    createActionModelParams[1] = interfaceMethod;
                    var actionModel = (ActionModel?)createActionModel.Invoke(DefaultModelProvider, createActionModelParams);
                    if (actionModel == null)
                        continue;

                    actionModel.Controller = controllerModel;
                    controllerModel.Actions.Add(actionModel);

                    foreach (var parameterInfo in actionModel.ActionMethod.GetParameters())
                    {
                        createParameterModelParams[0] = parameterInfo;
                        var parameterModel = (ParameterModel?)createParameterModel.Invoke(DefaultModelProvider, createParameterModelParams);
                        if (parameterModel != null)
                        {
                            parameterModel.Action = actionModel;
                            actionModel.Parameters.Add(parameterModel);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int Order => DefaultModelProvider.Order + 1;
}
```